# Ignore some files in IPython tab completion in linux

Tags: ipython

When I am working in IPython 5.0, sometimes I want to run a script with `run script.py`, but the tab completion will show me options `run script.py` and `run script.py~`, that is, Emacs backup files. How can I set to ignore these and other files like one does with `FIGNORE` in bash?

Comment: I don't think there's currently any configuration option to filter the files included in tab completion. We're planning to rework the completion machinery for IPython 6, so we'll try to keep this in mind as a feature request.